# Running python scripts in blender

Tags: blender

I am trying to run a script called sun exposure that is written for blender but when I try I am getting this message that is below. What is wrong?
The Message:

> File “\exposure.py.001”, line50
>   print ”There are” + str(px_w) + “ White pixel, and ” + str(px_b) + “black ones.”
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Location: unknown location:1
>
> Python script fail, look in the console for now…

Comment: Are the quotes in the file actually curly quotes, or did you just paste them wrong? If they're curly quotes you should replace them with straight quotes.

Comment: Can you share the script or a link to where you got it? The error you show indicates it may be an old script for blender 2.49 as 2.50+ uses python3.x - py2 uses `print "this"` while py3 is `print("this")`

Answer (score 0):

Blender uses Python 3, so you need to use brackets in print:

print **(**”There are” + str(px_w) + “ White pixel, and ” + str(px_b) + “black ones.”**)**